# Please help identify this component, marked 222F

Tags: capacitor, identification, components

I think it's a capacitor marked "222F"  (2,200pF) +/-1%.  However, it seems encased and has 4 pins instead of 2.    Two seem to be for the capacitor and the other two for the plastic looking bracket around it.    First I thought it was a coupled inductor of sort. Peaking inside a small opening it looks like a capacitor based on the color.  It's about 3mm x 3mm x 2mm square.   The arrows point to the mounts, there is one more on the other side not showing in the picture.  Thank you.

[image: Photo 1 of component on PCB]

[image: Photo 2 of component on PCB]

[image: Photo 3 of component on PCB]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are Panasonic's "Coil Type EMI Filter" as given in [Armandas' answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/486688/103420). I just wanted to add some extra info.

They are mostly T type LC filters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI1US6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The numbers indicate the capacitance inside the module. So, "222" means 2200pF. The module acts as 3rd order LPF and each model has a different cutoff frequency:

[image]

**Panasonic has stopped manufacturing those, so the whole series became obsolete.** But if you want to replace it (unlikely) you may be able to find at Digikey.

Comment: Fortunately there are often compatible replacements, with the same parameter and same PCB footprint. It doesn't even have to be the same brand. The chart above can help you select a filter with the same dB loss patern.

Comment: @Fredled `Fortunately there are often compatible replacements, with the same parameter and same PCB footprint. It doesn't even have to be the same brand.` true, but it isn't that easy to find a "fully replacement" to the product above since it has a maximum DC current rating of 2A. Today's popular T type tiny LC filter modules have a maximum current rating of 250mA or maybe 500mA.

Comment: Wow!   Thank you very much everyone for the quick and extremely thorough answers/research!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it could be [Panasonic ELKEA222FA](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/circuit-protection/filters/lineup/emi-filters/series/70475/model/72121) T-Filter.

[image]

EDIT: How to find a the right part:

1. Seeing a capacitor in the middle, gives a clue that it may be a T-filter.
2. Google `smd t filter` and browse images.
3. If an image looks similar, follow the links to find the part number.

Comment: You may well have found the correct part.  A summary of what the part is and what lead you to it would help make this a good answer.  Maybe include section of the datasheet showing the part and its specifications.

Comment: This is a link only answer.  Those are frowned on here.

Comment: Can you explicitly say that it is a T-filter rather than implying it as a search term?

Comment: Wow!   Thank you very much everyone for the quick and extremely thorough answer/research!  I really appreciate it.                                                                     
Note: Yes, I tried the google image search first but I was looking for a 4 pin/leads capacitor and/or inductor coil.